# Error: invalid_client The OAuth client was not found

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-oauth, google-apps

I read all the similar questions and the answer is always to set a product name inside the "Consent screen", but the problem is I can't find "Consent screen" under "APIs & auth". What I see under "APIs & auth" is just "APIs", "Credentials", and "Push".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Developers Console UI is changing. The Consent Screen is now under APIs & auth -> Credentials -> OAuth consent screen.